# SQL Server WHERE clause default to all unless variable entered

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of about 10 columns of data and I'd like to be able to make a stored procedure that pulls only the relevant data based on user-defined parameters. A simplified version of the `fact.Spend` table looks like this:

```
Location  |  Year  |  SpendYear
----------+--------+-----------
New York  |  2015  |  25.00
New York  |  2016  |  23.20
Dallas    |  2015  |  29.30
Dallas    |  2016  |  25.32
San Fran  |  2015  |  23.33
San Fran  |  2016  |  23.97
```

A very basic version of what I'm trying to do with this is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spPullSpendData 
    (@Location VARCHAR(20), @SpendYear SMALLINT)
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM fact.Spend
    WHERE Location = @Location
      AND SpendYear = @SpendYear
```

But I'd like for the `@SpendYear` parameter to be optional, defaulting to all years if there is no user input. I tried a few variations using subqueries, but so far nothing's worked out quite right.

Comment: use `WHERE Location = @Location AND (SpendYear = @SpendYear OR @SpendYear IS NULL);`

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    fact.Spend
WHERE
    (Location = @Location)
AND 
    (SpendYear = @SpendYear or @SpendYear IS NULL)
```